# Fetch data from firebase firestore and plot histogram using highcharts when cardview clicked - android

Tags: android, firebase, highcharts, google-cloud-firestore, android-cardview

I have an activity in which there are many card views which when clicked should fetch the data from firebase firestore and plot the data in a histogram format using highcharts in android.On each card view click event the d of that cardview is passed in the firestore query and the related data is retrieved.But in my case, the card view works only on second click and also when a different card view is clicked it retains the value of the previous query and only on second click it shows the correct data.

Below is my code for the adapter view which has the cardviews.

```
   DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("Users").document(tId).collection("Subjects")
                .document(subId).collection("Marks").document(testList.get(position).getMarksID());

           holder.show_graph.setOnClickListener(v -> {

               docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                   mMarks = new HashSet<>();
                   if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                       Map<String, Object> hm = documentSnapshot.getData();
                       Set<String> a = hm.keySet();
                       for (String b : a) {
                           try {
                               holder.marks_obtained.setText((String)documentSnapshot.get(email));

                               if(!b.equals("Max_marks")){
                                   Log.e( "onComplete: ", documentSnapshot.get(b+".com") + "  " +documentSnapshot.getId() );
                                   mMarks.add(Float.parseFloat((String)documentSnapshot.get(b+".com")));
                               }
                           } catch (Exception e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }
                   }
               });

            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.graph_plot,null);
            final View alertLayout = v;

            try{
                //HICharts
                HIChartView chartView =  alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.hc);
                chartView.plugins = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("histogram-bellcurve"));

                HIOptions options = new HIOptions();

                HIChart chart = new HIChart();
                chart.setType("variwide");
                options.setChart(chart);

                HITitle title = new HITitle();
                title.setText("Score Division");
                options.setTitle(title);

                HIXAxis xaxis1 = new HIXAxis();
                HITitle ht = new HITitle();
                ht.setText("Count");
                xaxis1.setTitle(ht);

                HIXAxis xaxis2 = new HIXAxis();
                xaxis2.setTitle(new HITitle());
                xaxis2.setOpposite(true);

                options.setXAxis(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(xaxis1, xaxis2)));

                HIYAxis yaxis1 = new HIYAxis();
                HITitle ht2 = new HITitle();
                ht2.setText("Marks");
                yaxis1.setTitle(ht2);

                HIYAxis yaxis2 = new HIYAxis();
                yaxis2.setTitle(new HITitle());
                yaxis2.setOpposite(true);

                options.setYAxis(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(yaxis1, yaxis2)));

                HILegend legend = new HILegend();
                legend.setEnabled(true);
                options.setLegend(legend);

                HIHistogram series1 = new HIHistogram();
                series1.setType("histogram");
                series1.setName("Histogram");
                series1.setXAxis(1);
                series1.setYAxis(1);
                series1.setBaseSeries("s1");
                series1.setZIndex(-1);

                HIScatter series2 = new HIScatter();
                series2.setType("scatter");
                series2.setName("Data");

                Number[] series2_data = new Number[mMarks.size()];

                int i = 0;
                for(float m : mMarks){
                    series2_data[i] = m;
                    i++;
                }

                series2.setId("s1");
                series2.setData(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(series2_data)));
                series2.setMarker(new HIMarker());
                series2.getMarker().setRadius(2.5);

                options.setSeries(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(series1, series2)));

                options.setExporting(new HIExporting());
                options.getExporting().setEnabled(false);

                chartView.setOptions(options);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                alertBox.setTitle("Graph");

                alertBox.setView(alertLayout);
                alertBox.setCancelable(false);

                alertBox.setPositiveButton("Done", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());

                AlertDialog dialog = alertBox.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e("",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            finally {
                if(mMarks != null){
                    mMarks.clear();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is not directly related with Highcharts library, but with implementation of card views.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not an expert in Java and Android. I'm just saying that is not the problem with JS (namely Highcharts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @daniel_s mentioned its not the problem with the highcharts. And Its not the problem with the firebase too. Its in the way in which you have put your code.

Now I am not the right person to say anything about firebase but lets understand this.
Firebase works on asynchronous mechanism and all the methods of the firebase are of asynchronous type. So when you click on the Cardview both firebase method and highchart methods runs together and not one after the other.

To make this work according to your way you should do something like this:

```
holder.show_graph.setOnClickListener(v -> {

               docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                   mMarks = new HashSet<>();
                   if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                       Map<String, Object> hm = documentSnapshot.getData();
                       Set<String> a = hm.keySet();
                       for (String b : a) {
                           try {
                               holder.marks_obtained.setText((String)documentSnapshot.get(email));

                               if(!b.equals("Max_marks")){
                                   Log.e( "onComplete: ", documentSnapshot.get(b+".com") + "  " +documentSnapshot.getId() );
                                   mMarks.add(Float.parseFloat((String)documentSnapshot.get(b+".com")));
                               }
                           } catch (Exception e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }
            // All of your highcharts code here.....
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.graph_plot,null);
            final View alertLayout = v;

            try{
                //HICharts
                HIChartView chartView =  alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.hc);
                chartView.plugins = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("histogram-bellcurve"));

                HIOptions options = new HIOptions();

                HIChart chart = new HIChart();
                chart.setType("variwide");
                options.setChart(chart);

                HITitle title = new HITitle();
                title.setText("Score Division");
                options.setTitle(title);

                HIXAxis xaxis1 = new HIXAxis();
                HITitle ht = new HITitle();
                ht.setText("Count");
                xaxis1.setTitle(ht);

                HIXAxis xaxis2 = new HIXAxis();
                xaxis2.setTitle(new HITitle());
                xaxis2.setOpposite(true);

                options.setXAxis(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(xaxis1, xaxis2)));

                HIYAxis yaxis1 = new HIYAxis();
                HITitle ht2 = new HITitle();
                ht2.setText("Marks");
                yaxis1.setTitle(ht2);

                HIYAxis yaxis2 = new HIYAxis();
                yaxis2.setTitle(new HITitle());
                yaxis2.setOpposite(true);

                options.setYAxis(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(yaxis1, yaxis2)));

                HILegend legend = new HILegend();
                legend.setEnabled(true);
                options.setLegend(legend);

                HIHistogram series1 = new HIHistogram();
                series1.setType("histogram");
                series1.setName("Histogram");
                series1.setXAxis(1);
                series1.setYAxis(1);
                series1.setBaseSeries("s1");
                series1.setZIndex(-1);

                HIScatter series2 = new HIScatter();
                series2.setType("scatter");
                series2.setName("Data");

                Number[] series2_data = new Number[mMarks.size()];

                int i = 0;
                for(float m : mMarks){
                    series2_data[i] = m;
                    i++;
                }

                series2.setId("s1");
                series2.setData(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(series2_data)));
                series2.setMarker(new HIMarker());
                series2.getMarker().setRadius(2.5);

                options.setSeries(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(series1, series2)));

                options.setExporting(new HIExporting());
                options.getExporting().setEnabled(false);

                chartView.setOptions(options);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                alertBox.setTitle("Graph");

                alertBox.setView(alertLayout);
                alertBox.setCancelable(false);

                alertBox.setPositiveButton("Done", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());

                AlertDialog dialog = alertBox.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e("",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            finally {
                if(mMarks != null){
                    mMarks.clear();
                }
            }
                   }
               });
```

Hope I was clear. If it worked then do accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark:)